# C# Socket Xamarin Отправка и получение данных от сервера

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

осуществляю подключение к серверу и отправку данных на него, получается приходил ответ от сервера но не открывается другое окно приложения, проверял точками остановки выполнения, код доходит до Navigation но не выполняется.

Но при этом если нажать отправку данных на сервер снова, после получения открывается это заветное окно (Но со второго раза).
Вызываю так:
`await Task.Run(() => EndReceiveAsync());`

КОД

```
public async Task EndReceiveAsync()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            try
            {
                int bytecount = sock.Receive(buffer);
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
                if (bytecount > 0)
                {
                    string code = reader.ReadString();
                    switch (code)
                    {
                        case "login":
                            {
                                if(reader.ReadString() == "noex")
                                {
                                    await DisplayAlert("Ошибка",reader.ReadString(),"Понятно..");
                                    return;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new PanelPage());
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `PushAsync` вызывается из другого потока. Выноси на главный поток.

Comment: Подскажи новичку, каким образом вынести?

Comment: Да я сам могу ошибаться, может проблема и не в этом, сейчас напишу в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эту часть поправить и для push, и для DisplayAlert:

```
if (reader.ReadString() == "noex")
{
    await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () =>
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Ошибка", reader.ReadString(), "Понятно..");
    });
    return;
}
else
{
    await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () =>
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new PanelPage());
    });
    return;
}
```

[`Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.invokeonmainthreadasync?view=xamarin-forms) выводит в основной поток, по идее, должно решить проблемы с открытием нового окна.

Comment: К сожалению всё равно только со второго раза открывает

Comment: Вопрос решил!
Спасибо!
Эт я затупил ))

Comment: Так а в чём проблема была в итоге? Можно попробовать ещё `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, а не `Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync`.

Comment: Да просто я не указывал основную форму в Navigation )))))))